# Insert text to wysiwyg from dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, wysiwyg

Is there a way on how to insert texts to bootstrap wysiwyg using jquery? 
By the way, I used bootstrap-wysihtml5 from this page http://jhollingworth.github.io/bootstrap-wysihtml5/
Texts are actually a template from a dropdown then onchange value selected should be inserted on the wysisyg.

I tried this code but it only inserts the texts on the hidden textarea not on the wysiwyg

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#template").change(function(){
        var template = $("#template").val();
        if(template != '') {
            $('.textarea, .wysihtml5-sandbox').append(template);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't simply access the `textarea` from the containing page's DOM since the actual WYSIWYG editor is in an iFrame with `.wysihtml5-sandbox`. So to access the iFrame's DOM and modify it, we'll have to first access the iFrame DOM:

```
  $('.wysihtml5-sandbox').contents() 
  //Now we have the iFrame DOM to apply selectors to

  $('.textarea', $('.wysihtml5-sandbox').contents())
  //Now we have access to the textarea which contains the editor's current text

  $('.textarea', $('.wysihtml5-sandbox').contents()).append('Hello World!')
  //Now we have appended content to the editor view, the original goal
```

Extra stuff:

```
$('.textarea', $('.wysihtml5-sandbox').contents()).removeClass('placeholder')
//Stops the text from being formatted as a placeholder (i.e. grayed out)
$('.textarea', $('.wysihtml5-sandbox').contents()).empty()
//Remove the existing placeholder text by emptying the textarea content
```

Comment: However, on page load and when I select a template from the dropdown, the inserted text/template was colored gray and the placeholder "MESSAGE" was not removed.. Any idea how to fix it? thanks a lot @sushain97

Comment: @markyorky how about `$('.textarea', $('.wysihtml5-sandbox').contents()).removeClass('placeholder')`?

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work..any other solution Sir? thanks!

Comment: the placeholder for the wysiwyg looks like this <iframe><body>MESSAGE</body></iframe>, how do we clear the word "MESSAGE"?

Comment: `removeClass` will stop the text from being formatted as a placeholder (i.e. grayed out) `$('.textarea', $('.wysihtml5-sandbox').contents()).empty()` will remove the existing placeholder text